# PostgreSQL: Summing info from Two Aggregated Tables

Tags: postgresql, join, aggregate

There is something wrong with my method or my logic here.

I am trying to sum all the data from both tables. If the two correspond, add them up, if either doesn't correspond, still show the individual query total, ending up with estimates per year in sequence.
I have tried LEFT JOINS, FULL JOINS, (UNIONS). Nothing comes close to just summing where possible and supplying the data otherwise.
The key point here is pb and th_year information are years when the results are needed.

The error must be obvious in my code.

The separate aggregate queries produce the correct results.

Its the combining of the two queries where I am going wrong.

Would appreciate advice on this.

I thought it would be simple.

I think it probably is simple. Just stupidity on my side.

```
CREATE VIEW public.cf_th_data_totals_by_year_by_wc_2
AS SELECT 

a.owner,
a.region,
a.district,
a.plantation,
b.th_year,
a.pb,
a.wc,

sum(a.tcf_calcarea + b.tth_calcarea) AS area,
sum(a.tcf_total + b.tth_total) AS total,
sum(a.tcf_ws + b.tth_ws) AS ws,
sum(a.tcf_util + b.tth_util) AS util,
sum(a.tcf_s + b.tth_s) AS s,
sum(a.tcf_a + b.tth_a) AS a,
sum(a.tcf_b + b.tth_b) AS b,
sum(a.tcf_c + b.tth_c) AS c,
sum(a.tcf_d + b.tth_d) AS d

 FROM
  (SELECT 
  cfdata.owner,
  cfdata.region,
  cfdata.district,
  cfdata.plantation,
  cfdata.pb,
  cfdata.wc,
  sum(cfdata.calcarea)AS tcf_calcarea,
  sum(cfdata._ba) AS tcf_ba,
  sum(cfdata._total) AS tcf_total,
  sum( cfdata._ws) AS tcf_ws,
  sum( cfdata._util) AS tcf_util,
  sum( cfdata._s) AS tcf_s,
  sum( cfdata._a) AS tcf_a,
  sum( cfdata._b) AS tcf_b,
  sum( cfdata._c) AS tcf_c,
  sum( cfdata._d) AS tcf_d

 FROM cfdata

 GROUP BY  cfdata.owner, cfdata.region, cfdata.district, cfdata.plantation, cfdata.pb, cfdata.wc 
 ORDER BY  cfdata.owner, cfdata.region, cfdata.district, cfdata.plantation, cfdata.pb, cfdata.wc) a


JOIN

(SELECT 
  thdata.owner,
  thdata.region,
  thdata.district,
  thdata.plantation,
  thdata.th_year,
  thdata.wc,
  sum(thdata.calcarea)AS tth_calcarea,
  sum(thdata.th_ba) AS tth_ba,
  sum(thdata.th_total) AS tth_total,
  sum(thdata.th_ws) AS tth_ws,
  sum(thdata.th_util) AS tth_util,
  sum(thdata.th_s) AS tth_s,
  sum(thdata.th_a) AS tth_a,
  sum(thdata.th_b) AS tth_b,
  sum(thdata.th_c) AS tth_c,
  sum(thdata.th_d) AS tth_d

FROM thdata

GROUP BY  thdata.owner, thdata.region, thdata.district, thdata.plantation, thdata.th_year, thdata.wc 
ORDER BY  thdata.owner, thdata.region, thdata.district, thdata.plantation, thdata.th_year, thdata.wc) b

 ON  a.owner = b.owner AND a.region = b.region AND a.district = b.district and a.plantation = b.plantation AND a.pb = b.th_year AND a.wc = b.wc

GROUP BY  a.owner, a.region, a.district, a.plantation, a.pb, b.th_year, a.wc 
ORDER BY  a.owner, a.region, a.district, a.plantation, a.pb, b.th_year, a.wc
```

thdata sample:

```
owner       region      district    plantation  compartment calcarea     wc  plantdate  th_year th_age   th_dbh  th_ht   th_vtree    th_sph  th_ba   th_total  th_ws     th_util     th_s    th_a    th_b    th_c    th_d    thdata_id
KeyProjects Northern    Marshlands  River Glen  A27         14.02       PFN 01/08/2009  2017    8        12.3    7.3     0.0289      179     28      70        14        56          42      14       0      0       0       1
KeyProjects Northern    Marshlands  River Glen  A28          2.1        ESN 01/12/2010  2012    2         4.5    4.2     0           479      2       0         0         0           0       0       0      0       0       2
KeyProjects Northern    Marshlands  River Glen  A28          2.1        ESN 01/12/2010  2014    4        10.2    9.6     0.0188      250      4      11         0         8           4       6       0      0       0       3
KeyProjects Northern    Marshlands  River Glen  A29         2.71        ESN 01/08/2009  2011    2         4.5    4.2     0           479      3       0         0         0           0       0       0      0       0       4
KeyProjects Northern    Marshlands  River Glen  A29         2.71        ESN 01/08/2009  2013    4        10.2    9.6     0.0188      250      5      14         0        11           5       8       0      0       0       5
```

thdata sample:

```
owner       region      district    plantation  compartment  wc     pb      calcarea     cfage   dbh    ht      vtree   sph     _ba   _total   _ws   _util   _s   _a     _b    _c   _d   tmai    umai    smai    cfdata_id
KeyProjects Northern    Marshlands  River Glen  A01          EF1    2021    5.27         10      14.5   20.4    0.1109  1004     90    585      21  564      84    401    79    0   0    11.1    10.7    1.5     1
KeyProjects Northern    Marshlands  River Glen  A02          EF1    2021    36.1         10      14.5   20.4    0.1109  1004    614   4007     144  3863    578   2744   542    0   0    11.1    10.7    1.5     2
KeyProjects Northern    Marshlands  River Glen  A03          EF1    2021    5.5          10      14.5   20.4    0.1109  1004     94    611      22  589      88    418    83    0   0    11.1    10.7    1.5     3
KeyProjects Northern    Marshlands  River Glen  A04          EF1    2021    11.91        10      14.5   20.4    0.1109  1004    202   1322      48  1274    191    905   179    0   0    11.1    10.7    1.5     4
KeyProjects Northern    Marshlands  River Glen  A05          EF1    2022    39.17        11      14.9   21.8    0.1286  1000    705   5053     157  4857    666   3486   744    0   0    11.7    11.3    1.7     5
```

expected result:

```
owner       region      district    plantation  th_year pb      wc  area    total   ws      util    s       a       b       c   d
KeyProjects Northern    Marshlands  River Glen  2008    2008    EF1 620.49  44176   1788    42389   7562    31953   2852    0   0
KeyProjects Northern    Marshlands  River Glen  2009    2009    EF1 635.65  44319   1778    42476   7634    31993   2852    0   0
KeyProjects Northern    Marshlands  River Glen  2010    2010    EF1 1202.31 87980   3453    84487   14906   63883   5704    0   0
KeyProjects Northern    Marshlands  River Glen  2011    2011    EF1 1948.37 132378  5275    127104  22662   95895   8556    0   0
KeyProjects Northern    Marshlands  River Glen  2012    2012    EF1 1378.61 87928   3429    84477   14878   63922   5704    0   0
```

Comment: It's a bit hard to follow with just the code. Couple you please include some sample data and the result you're trying to achieve?

Comment: @Mureinik Some data and expected result added.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, you have a few issues with your query:

- In the main query, do not use `sum(a.tcf_calcarea + b.tth_calcarea) AS area`. You can simply add but you should make sure to substitute any `NULL` values with `0` first: write `coalesce(a.tcf_calcarea, 0) + coalesce(b.tth_calcarea, 0) AS area` instead, for all `sum()`s. This also means you are not aggregating anymore at this level, so you should drop the final `GROUP BY` clause.
- Now make a `FULL OUTER JOIN` between the two sub-queries. This means you get all rows from both sub-queries joined and where a corresponding row does not exist for either side, there are `NULL`s for column values.
- It makes no sense to `ORDER BY` in a sub-query, the planner will process the row set in the way it sees best. You should order at the outer level only.
- By definition (join condition) `b.th_year = a.pb` so you can drop one of the two columns.

Some syntactical pointers:

- Your sub-queries use only one table so there is no need to work with table aliases, saves you a lot a typing.
- More savings: Use positional parameters in your `GROUP BY` clause, so you can write `GROUP BY 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6`. Same with `ORDER BY`.
- On the `JOIN` clause you can write `USING (owner, region, district, plantation, wc)` and then add `WHERE a.pb = b.th_year`. Other than that being shorter, you do not need sub-query aliases in the main query anymore for any of the `USING` columns. However, the fact that one join condition does not have corresponding column names does make things slightly more confused; up to you.

All in all, this is what you get:

```
CREATE VIEW public.cf_th_data_totals_by_year_by_wc_2 AS
  SELECT owner, region, district, plantation, b.th_year, wc,
         coalesce(a.tcf_calcarea, 0) + coalesce(b.tth_calcarea, 0) AS area,
         ...
  FROM (
    SELECT owner, region, district, plantation, pb, wc,
           sum(calcarea) AS tcf_calcarea,
           ...
    FROM cfdata
    GROUP BY 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6) a
  FULL JOIN (
    SELECT owner, region, district, plantation, th_year, wc,
           sum(calcarea) AS tth_calcarea,
           ...
    FROM thdata
    GROUP BY 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6) b
  USING (owner, region, district, plantation, wc)
  WHERE a.pb = b.th_year
  ORDER BY 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6;
```

Comment: Hi @Patrick. Thank you for the tips and code. They are greatly appreciated. The code with the necessary entries gives only 5 lines as a result, to the few hundred expected. Maybe there is something wrong with my underlying tables as far as normalization is concerned. Will attach result shortly.

Comment: Is this perhaps related to `a.pb = th_year` or `wc` values? In the sample data the values are not matching. It unlikely has anything to do with the other join conditions.

Comment: You are 100% correct @Patrick. The 5 lines produced were the only ones where the other conditions but especially the 'wc' and 'pb' values corresponded. However, I want the totals from each table where they don't correspond, as long as the 'wc' and 'pb' are shown, so I have a list of data for those years from each table and the combined totals as well. That was my original goal.

Comment: In that case you should remove them from the join conditions and/or not group on them. I really can't be any more specific because your question and sample data don't provide any clues as to how to do the joining and aggregation in this case.

Comment: This is what I am getting. @Patrick. [link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/gvvld5lo63ly62q/result.png?dl=0) I included 'pb' and 'th_year' to see what is going on. Just for interest's sake.

Comment: Hi John, try to set up a fiddle here: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!15. That should work a lot easier.

Comment: Will do so @Patrick. Can I use postgresql backup, plain, to get the data in sql format to set up the tables? It doesn't seem to like that option. Must something be removed from the backup data? Also, do I just paste, or use "Text to DDL" Will have to deal with this a few hours from now.